# jQuery accessing cloned item

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a unordered list like:

```
<ul>
   <li data-id="1" data-value="text"> My text </li>
   <li data-id="2" data-value="movie"> My movie </li>
   <li data-id="3" data-value="text"> Another text </li>
   <li data-id="4" data-value="picture"> Picture </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using jQuery Quicksand plugin to sort that list:

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

The problem is I'm using jQuery on these links (code below is just an rewritten example, may not work):

```
jQuery("li").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 500);
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```

And till now everything works fine.

But Quicksand operates on TWO lists, so I'm creating the second one dynamically:

```
 jQuery('document').ready(function(){    
        //create a clone of the full list of elements and extract 'li' elements
        //in order to use it as the 'second' list for quicksand
        var cache_list = jQuery('ul').clone();

        //Add on click event handler to the 'ALL' button
        jQuery('ul.portfolio-terms li a[data-value=All]').click(function(e) {
                //Call quicksand on the original works_list list(the one visible to the user)
                //pass to it all the 'li' elements from the cached clone 
                //since we want to display them all
                jQuery('.portfolio-list').quicksand( cache_list.find('li'), {
                  duration: 500,
                });
            e.preventDefault();
(...)
```

And after sorting (clicking, for example "All" link) my jQuery overlays/animations doesn't work. I believe that's because my jQuery code is not attached to dynamically "produced" cloned list. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach your animation with [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
jQuery("li").live({
        mouseover:
           function() {
             jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 0.2}, 500);  
           },
        mouseout:
           function() {
             jQuery(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
           }
       }
    );
```

That way, every future `li` element will also get these same events.